# How do I have multiple devs on 1 game? IOS and Android store

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase, ads, account

Lets say I want to have 1 dev implement ads 1 in app purchases and another do social media. Do I have to share my Apple dev/google dev account with all of them? or is there another way for them to edit my game and implement those features without access to my account? how? any links to tutorials will be appreciated thanks

Comment: How about using version control like Git? That way each dev can be working on a separate branch of the project(s), which when finished/tested etc. can be merged back to the master branch.

Comment: But does all dev need access to my account for things like Game Center, leaderbaord, IAP, or Playstore leaderboards iap etc? or can they work on those without access to the account that will upload it.

Comment: With regards iOS, I believe you can set up test accounts for in app purchases, and they won't actually need to log in the account, just use the test account details within the code. As for Game Centre, unfortunately I do not have experience, the same goes for Google Play.

Hopefully someone else will be able to give a better idea.